# How to change dir in tcsh without chaging cd -

Tags: linux, unix, tcsh

I am using tcsh.

I want to create an alias where I `cd` into another directory and execute a command.

But I dont want to touch `cd -`. How do i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
PS: The other directory has a script that uses local relative paths, thats why I have to `cd` into that dir.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute your command in the appropriate directory.

If I am in `/home/hardknock/Documents/` and I dont want to leave this directory but I want to delete something in `/etc/` I can just `sudo rm -r /etc/folder_name/` and I will never have left `Documents`.

The same logic applies to pretty much any CLI command.

Comment: This would not work since the other directory has a script that has local paths.

Answer (score 0):

Because `-` is an alias to *the last directory I was in*, you could, rather complicatedly preserve it using the directory history stack:

```
pushd -
pushd -
cd /
do command here
popd
popd
```

I'm sure there's a better way of accomplishing this, but this is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in subshell!

```
alias myalias '(cd /to/directory; run_commands)'
```